# ember serve and browser reload results in "cannot GET /foo" with custom Ember.Location

Tags: ember.js

**TL;DR: Added custom location type to `environment.js` then `ember serve` -> open browser to route /foo -> `cannot GET /foo`**

Followed the instructions at https://www.emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Location.html#toc_custom-implementation and copied the code exactly as it appeared into a file called `app/locations/history-url-logging.js`, added a line to `config/environment.js` that said:

```
ENV.locationType = 'history-url-logging';
```

For reference, the code given in the docs is simply:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.HistoryLocation.extend({
    implementation: 'history-url-logging',

    pushState: function (path) {
        console.log(path);
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

I decided to restart the server, did the usual `CTRL+C` to `ember s` then did `ember s` again. I went back to my browser sitting on one of the routes, hit `F5`, and received the cryptic error:

**`Cannot GET /contacts`**

So, after MUCH Googling and trial and error (and posting a previous question here which I just edited with this text you're reading), I discovered that to FIX that error, all I had to do remove the config line `ENV.locationType = 'history-url-logging';`, restart the server (`ember s`), and suddenly the app worked fine!

What's even more odd is that if I *start* the app without that line in `environment.js`, then once the app is running (and the browser window reloads just fine, etc), then I *re-add* the line that says `ENV.locationType = 'history-url-logging';` (which triggers a live reload), and the app *still* works fine! (E.g. hitting F5 to reload the page doesn't vie me the "Cannot GET /contacts" (or whatever the route is) error.) And, of course, the console gives me the "console.log" output as expected from the code above.

So, long and short of it, using a custom location totally seems to screw up `ember serve` - which is really sad and frustrating! Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Where did `"page-stack"` implementation come from? I believe that the implementation string should be the same as the file name, meaning `"history-url-logging"`.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right, that was an error in my copy-pasting. I copied my code before I reverted it for testing. In the test, the `implementation` **is** `history-url-logging`, guarantee it. Still same problem. :-/ - I'll edit my question so other's aren't confused - thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

Ember built-in server looks at the environment.js locationType property to figure out if it must serve routes after the rootURL path. By default, if the locationType is `history` it will do it. It uses string matching.

In your case you wrote your own location, inheriting from HistoryLocation therefor the locationType property in the environement.js is now `history-url-logging`. The built-in server doesn't recognize it as a history based form of location just by the name. It will default to hash location. It doesn't analyze your code.

For this scenario, we have to help the built-in server to understand that the locationType is equivalent to a history location.
You need to add `historySupportMiddleware: true` in your environment.js file right after the locationType property.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Are you able to add an explanation of why/how your solution helps answer the OP's question?

Comment: @MattShepherd I got your point. I edited my response. Hopefully it will help.